# Correct xslt/xpath syntax for accessing xml nodes retrieved from REST API call

Tags: xml, rest, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

First time posting, so please excuse my naivete. I am currently trying to transform an xml file for the Structured Product Labeling of Avycaz retrieved from the National Library of Medicine's [DailyMed](http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/drugInfo.cfm?setid=d9c2803f-dc9c-4b19-b4a3-8303bc8c15fd) website. I want to insert data obtained via REST response from the RxNav API (located at: [RxNav API](https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/Prescribe)) into my resulting transformation.

My setup:

Avycaz.xml (too large to include below) + my.xslt + REST_response.xml = output.xml

REST_response.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rxnormdata>
  <idGroup>
    <idType>NDC</idType>
    <id>0456-2700-10</id>
    <rxnormId>1603845</rxnormId>
  </idGroup>
</rxnormdata>
```

REST_response.xml API call within my.xslt:

```
https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/Prescribe/rxcui?idtype=NDC&id=0456-2700-10
```

my.xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="rxnav" version="2.0" 
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2004/07/xpath-functions" 
  xmlns:rxnav="https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/"
  xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xpath-default-namespace="urn:hl7-org:v3"
  xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/spl/schema/spl.xsd">
  <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="NDC" select="'0456-2700-10'"/>
  <!--This data would actually be imported from Avycaz.xml
      Hence all of the xmlns attributes above-->

  <xsl:variable name="REST_response" 
    select="document(concat('https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/Prescribe/rxcui?idtype=NDC&amp;id=',
    $NDC))"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element exclude-result-prefixes="#all" name="api-tests">
        <para>
            <xsl:text>NDC: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$NDC"/>
        </para>
        <para>
            <xsl:text>RxCUI_1: 
            </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$REST_response"/>
            <xsl:text>
     Result: Fail</xsl:text>
        </para>
        <para>
            <xsl:text>RxCUI_2: 
            </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$REST_response/rxnormdata/idGroup/rxnormId"/>
            <xsl:text>
     Result: Fail</xsl:text>
        </para>
        <para>
            <xsl:text>RxCUI_3: 
            </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$REST_response//rxnormId"/>
            <xsl:text>
     Result: Fail</xsl:text>
        </para>
        <para>
            <xsl:text>RxCUI_4: 
            </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$REST_response//rxnav:rxnormId"/>
            <xsl:text>
     Result: Fail</xsl:text>
        </para>
        <para>
            <xsl:text>RxCUI_5: 
            </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$REST_response//*[local-name()[contains(., 'rxnormId')]]/text()"/>
            <xsl:text>
     Result: Success</xsl:text>
        </para>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output.xml:

```
<api-tests>
 <para>NDC: 0456-2700-10</para>
 <para>RxCUI_1: 
       NDC0456-2700-101603845
       Result: Fail</para>
 <para>RxCUI_2: 

       Result: Fail</para>
 <para>RxCUI_3: 

       Result: Fail</para>
 <para>RxCUI_4: 

       Result: Fail</para>
 <para>RxCUI_5: 
       1603845
       Result: Success</para>
</api-tests>
```

I want to insert the data in the `<rxnormId>`1603845`<rxnormId>` element into my resulting transformation. The only method I have tried that works uses the XPATH statement: `$REST_response//*[local-name()[contains(., 'rxnormId')]]/text()`

Is there a better method that actually accesses the node and does not involve string matching?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using `xpath-default-namespace="urn:hl7-org:v3"`. The REST response isn't in a namespace, so your xpath doesn't match.

What you can do is match `rxnormId` in any namespace by using `*` for the prefix:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$REST_response//*:rxnormId"/>
```

If you want to make sure you only match `rxnormId` in no namespace, you can test the namespace uri:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$REST_response//*:rxnormId[namespace-uri()='']"/>
```

Comment: Wow, thank  you so much for the quick and workable response! I thought it was probably a namespace issue. I tried both of your suggestions and they worked like a charm. Such a great first experience with a asking a question here.

Answer (score 0):

Find it by id directly like so:

```
//rxnnormid
```

Answer (score 0):

As already explained, your stylesheet has `xpath-default-namespace="urn:hl7-org:v3"`. Either remove that if you don't want or need to select elements in that namespace or override it locally, as in `<xsl:value-of xpath-default-namespace="" select="$REST_response/rxnormdata/idGroup/rxnormId"/>`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response as well. Both yours and the above responses worked. Thank you for the explanation and contributing to a wonderful first experience posting a question on here!